# Trying to open Google Earth via a Script, file path nonexistent

Tags: python, terminal, filepath

I am trying to build a script that opens the Google Earth.app which I can see in Finder, but when I go to the applications folder it is not present. I looked at some other posts to find the filepath of Google Earth.app via `sudo find / -iname *.app`, which was `/Applications/Google Earth.app`. When I try and find this file I get 'No such file or directory'. Could some one please explain why you applications that are in Finder don't show up in terminal? Also how would I find the correct file path so I can use subprocess.Popen() to open Google Earth in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems going on here:

1) That path is probably correct. You're not using find correctly, in particular. You need to do `sudo find / -name "*.app"` (note the quotes around `*app`). From the man page:

> -iname pattern
>       Like -name, but the match is case insensitive. For example, the patterns 'fo*' and 'F??' match the file names 'Foo', 'FOO', 'foo', 'fOo', etc. In these patterns, unlike filename expansion by the shell, an initial '.' can be matched by '*'. That is, find -name *bar will match the file '.foobar'. Please note that you should quote patterns as a matter of course, otherwise the shell will expand any wildcard characters in them.

2) Try using `subprocess.Popen(["/Applications/Google Earth.app"], shell=True)`. Don't worry too much about security problems with `shell=True` unless you are taking user input. If it's just hardcoded to use your path to Google Earth, you're fine. If you have user input in your logic, however, ***DO NOT*** use `shell=True`. `shell=True` just means that shell metacharacters will work if they are in the command. The reason you need it is that `subprocess.Popen()` will have trouble parsing your command since there is a space in the path. Alternatively, you could just use `os.system("/Applications/Google Earth.app")`.

Comment: When I try and run this file it says that No such file or directory exists still. How can I change to the directory where this app is so I can print the pwd. When I go to the Applications folder I don't actually see the file `Google Earth.app.` is it hidden some how?

Comment: Without being able to see your file system, I'm really not sure...doing a `find` over `/` should always do the trick (though it may take a very long time for it to run). What OS are you using?

Comment: `os.chdir(the_directory_you_want_to_go_to)` changes the working directory, btw. `os.getcwd()` will give you the current working directory (cwd for short, hence the function name)